# Ubuntu on portable SSD - choosing between UEFI and Legacy

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, portable

I want to install Ubuntu Mate on a portable SSD, and be able to use it on two Windows 10 computers, a desktop and a laptop.

The problem is, the desktop is quite old, and boots Windows 10 in Legacy mode, but the laptop is brand new, and boots in UEFI mode.

If I choose to boot Ubuntu in Legacy mode, won't it boot on my laptop, and won't it boot on my desktop if I choose UEFI mode?

Do I have to change the BIOS in one of the computers, so they both boot in either Legacy, or UEFI?

**Edit**
On desktop: ASRock UEFI Setup Utility says:
PCI ROM Priority: EFI Compatible ROM
(However msinfo32 says the computer is booted in Legacy mode)
On laptop UEFI mode according to msinfo32. Secure Boot is enabled, and Legacy Support disabled. I can get to the Boot menu with ESC + F9 at startup.

Comment: You could set up the SSD to boot either way, but that may not even be necessary if one of your machines allows you  to select a mode preference (UEFI or legacy first).  What boot options do your machines offer?

Comment: In addition to @ubfan1 comment: Setting up your external SSD in a way which supports UEFI and legacy is a very tricky thing and often goes wrong, wasting your time. If your UEFI system still supports legacy first boot you can set it to that, and create an legacy installation which then will work on both machines.

Comment: OK, I will try to make a UEFI Ubuntu live USB, and see if it works on both of my machines. If not, I'll revert to a Legacy Ubuntu. The BIOS utility of the desktop (see new info in the original question) suggests it supports UEFI.

Comment: Short update - booted an old Ubuntu Mate 17.04, I had on a live USB. It booted perfectly on both machines in UEFI mode, according to the output of `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS`. I won't close the question yet, not until I've actually made the full install SSD successfully.

Comment: The Mate 17.04 messed up my clock on the new laptop, but not on the old desktop, strange, though outside the scope of this question. However WiFi worked on the laptop, not on the desktop.